# AWS Amplify i18n internationalization in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, aws-amplify

translate.ts

```
const dict = {
   'bh': {
      'Hello there!': "Apa khabar di sana!"   
  },
  'ch': {
      'Hello there!': "你好！"
  }
};

I18n.putVocabularies(dict);
I18n.setLanguage('ch');
I18n.get('Hello there!');
```

translate.html

```
<h3>(how to call function to get translation)</h3>
```

I am trying to translate website texts in different languages using AWS amplify i18n feature. I am following AWS-amplify reference https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/utilities/i18n/q/platform/js#setlanguage

But I am struggling with calling function from HTML to show in Chinese language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "get" isn't assigned to a variable. 
Try assigning the get to a variable and bind it to the UI.

```
this.text = I18n.get('Hello There');
```

Then in your HTML

```
<p>{{text}}</p>
```